# Problema en una relación de uno a muchos entre modelos de laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Buenas tengo el siguiente problema tengo dos modelos relacionados. Cuando ingreso `$articulo = \App\Articulo::find(1)->categoria` para obtener la categoría correspondiente a ese articulo hasta ahi bien porque obtengo esos datos. Pero cuando ingreso `$articulo->categoria->nombre`para obtener una propiedad especifica me arroja el siguiente error.

> PHP error:  Trying to get property of non-object on line 1

He realizado todo esto de la mano de la documentacion de laravel ya que me encuentro aprendiendolo.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships

Migracion - Tabla Categorias

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categorias', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nombre', 50);
            $table->string('descripcion', 50);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Migracion - Tabla Articulos

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('articulos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('categoria_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('categoria_id')->references('id')->on('categorias');
            $table->string('codigo', 50);
            $table->string('nombre', 50);
            $table->integer('stock');
            $table->string('descripcion', 50);
            $table->string('estado', 50);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Modelo Categoria

```
class Categoria extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categorias';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $filliable = ['nombre', 'descripcion'];

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function articulos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Articulo');
    }
}
```

Modelo Articulo

```
class Articulo extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'articulos';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $filliable = [
        'categoria_id', 
        'codigo', 
        'nombre', 
        'stock',
        'descripcion',
        'estado'
        ];

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function categoria()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Categoria');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al hacer:

```
$articulo = \App\Articulo::find(1)->categoria
```

Estás obteniendo la categoría, y no el artículo, por lo cual si haces:

```
$articulo->categoria->nombre
```

No va a encontrar otra relación categoria, puesto que ya estás en dicha relación (a menos que tengas otra, cosa que no creo).

---

Si continúas usando dicha convención, entonces tal vez funcione si haces:

```
$articulo->nombre;
```

Para obtener el nombre de la categoría, pero creo que simplemente deberías hacer:

```
$articulo = \App\Articulo::find(1);
```

y de esa forma obtienes el artículo en la variable $articulo, y ahí sí te funcionará:

```
$articulo->categoria->nombre
```

Para obtener el nombre de la categoría.

Comment: Gracias me sirvió mucho tu ayuda viendo la documentación de laravel como yo lo tenia era para cuando se tiene "hasmany".